# Why ||T|| is attainable?

Tags: normed-spaces

I am having trouble to understand why sup will turn out to max. It is from Kesavan Functional Analysis. I know realvalued continuous functions on compact space attend maximum value but here the domain is closed unit interval minus origin which is not compact. How can I use that result here:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{\Vert Tx \Vert}{\Vert x \Vert}= \left\Vert T\left(\frac{x}{\Vert x \Vert}\right)\right\Vert,$$
thus $$ \sup_{0<\Vert x \Vert \le 1} \frac{\Vert Tx \Vert}{\Vert x \Vert} = \sup_{\Vert y \Vert=1}\Vert Ty \Vert.$$
Now on the RHS you take the supremum of a continuous function over the compact unit sphere $\{y \in \mathbb{R}^n \vert ~ \Vert y \Vert =1\}$ and thus the supremum is attained.

Answer (score 0):

Because $Sup_{\|T(x)\|\leq 1}{{\|T(x)\|}\over {\|x\|}}=\|T({x\over{\|x\|}})\|$ is $Sup_{\|T(x)\|= 1}{{\|T(x)\|} }$ which is attained since $\|T(x)\|$ is a continuous function and a continuous function defined on a compact set attains its maximum.